# Fetch existing wl_surfaces ?

Tags: wayland

Is that is possible to fetch an existing wl_surfaces ?

The idea is to be able to fetch a wl_surfaces from an application and be able to acceed all of its data, such as its wl_buffer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One client cannot access the surfaces of another client.

Comment: Looks like. For my needs i hacked weston compositor and i was able to do what i wanted to do.

Comment: Right. You can indeed implement your own compositor, or hack Weston.